# What is VB.NET equivalent of this way to create instance?

Tags: .net, vb.net, class, properties, instance

In C# you can create an instance like this:

```
Custom mycustomelement = new Custom { ElenentName = "My Custom Element" };
```

I wonder how I can create instance like this in Visual Basic and what this type of creating instance is called.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called an [object initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers), and the [corresponding VB.NET syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/how-to-declare-an-object-by-using-an-object-initializer) is:

```
Dim mycustomelement As New Custom With { .ElementName = "My Custom Element" }
```

(Note the dot (`.`) before the property name, which matches the syntax of VB's `With` statement.)

---

Note that there is a subtle difference between C# and VB when using the [object initializer syntax for *anonymous types*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/object-initializers-named-and-anonymous-types#anonymous-types): In C#, all properties are immutable; in VB, they are mutable unless they are initialized with the `Key` keyword.