# Equality of anonymous has different behavior than expexted

Tags: .net, vb.net

While in the .net documentation is mentioned very clearly that the equality
of anonymous type in the same assembly depends on the equality of the names and values of the fields i get different behavior

```
  Dim anonymous1 = New With {.texta = "a", .textb = "b"}
  Dim anonymous2 = New With {.texta = "a", .textb = "b"}

  Dim compare = anonymous1.Equals(anonymous2)
```

**The compare variable is false and the hashcodes also different**.

This is a very serious problem for me because linq GroupBy function with key an anonymous type does not group at all the data because  all the keys are not equal.

Comment: `Dim anonymous1 = New With {Key .texta = "a", Key .textb = "b"}` etc. Recent => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70896475/what-is-vb-net-equivalent-of-this-way-to-create-instance

Comment: This is covered in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/anonymous-types#equality)

Comment: Duplicate of [What's the equivalent VB.NET syntax for anonymous types in a LINQ statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142225/whats-the-equivalent-vb-net-syntax-for-anonymous-types-in-a-linq-statement) and [How do VB.NET anonymous types without key fields differ from C# anonymous types when compared?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21703707/8967612)

Comment: Thank you for your help but do you know how i can insert the Key Properties when i create the anonymous type dynamicaly with TypeBuilder?

Comment: It's defined as a **Sealed** / ConstructedGeneric / GenericType. That's why I pointed you to that question. Read the final section of the answer.